# how does elasticsearch-hadoop create two RDDs based on different ES clusters

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, elasticsearch-hadoop

I need to join two Rdds from two different ES clusters,but I found I just can create one SparkConf and SparkContext based on one ES cluster. For example the code as following:

```
var sparkConf: SparkConf = new SparkConf()
sparkConf.set("es.nodes", "192.168.0.22:9200")
val rdd1=sc.esRDD("userIndex1/type1")
```

So how can I create two RDD from different ES clusters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `cfg` parameter for `esRDD`. You can use `val rdd1=sc.esRDD("userIndex1/type1", Map("es.nodes" -> "192.168.0.22:9200")` to set the configuration.

Comment: Great! I did't find it in official doc, how did you get know it please, by reading source code?

Comment: yep. Just took a look at `esRDD` here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/blob/master/spark/core/main/scala/org/elasticsearch/spark/rdd/EsSpark.scala#L23